# Why Word2Vec is called a neural model if no neural network is used in it?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, word2vec, books

Word2Vec model does not use any neural network. It uses logistic regression only.

Consider the following paragraph from p:18 of [Vector Semantics and Embeddings](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/6.pdf)

> We’ll  see  how  to  do  neural  networks  in  the  next  chapter,
> but  **word2vec  is  a much simpler model than the neural network
> language model**, in two ways.  First,word2vec simplifies the task
> (making it binary classification instead of word prediction). Second,
> word2vec simplifies the architecture (**training a logistic
> regression classifier instead of a multi-layer neural network with
> hidden layers that demand more sophisticated training algorithms**). The
> intuition of skip-gram is:
>
> 1. Treat the target word and a neighboring context word as positive examples.
> 2. Randomly sample other words in the lexicon to get negative samples.
> 3. Use logistic regression to train a classifier to distinguish those two cases.
> 4. Use the learned weights as the embeddings.

But, why it is called a neural model then? Is there any version of Word2Vec that use neural network?

Comment: Please write a comment for downvote so that I can improve my question.

Comment: The Wikipedia article for word2vec https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec says that a neural network is indeed used: "The word2vec algorithm uses a neural network model to learn word associations from a large corpus of text." What made you think that a neural network isn't used?

Comment: @ThePointer But the textbook I read is saying differently. It is using logistic regression only.

Comment: Please provide a reference to your textbook and where it is implied that word2vec only uses logistic regression.

Comment: @ThePointer I updated the question. If there are several variants, please provide an answer, if possible, that there are several variants for the same Word2Vec model and one of them uses neural network

Comment: This is beyond my level of knowledge at the moment, so it's best to leave it to someone else.

Comment: Logistic regression can and often is accomplished through logistic regression.  That's what a binary or sentiment analysis is.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer *Logistic regression can and often is accomplished through logistic regression*... Do you mean *Logistic regression can and often is accomplished through neural network*?

Comment: @hanugm Yes, that's exactly what I meant.  Oops. :)